# How to count the number of User Signups by date and push it onto a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table of entries for user signup that goes back to 2017.

How would I count the number of entries in the user sign ups table by day, and push the records into a csv? Preferably a script that runs in the console

For example my csv would look something like this

Calendar Date, Number of entries created that day

2017-12-01,    50

........

2020-06-01,    20

2020-06-02,    32

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using to  do this? simply you can group dates in your mysql query and count each group.

Comment: I'm trying to do this through a script in rails console, where it can all be done in go, since there are lots of dates, and I want the count of user sign ups per day